# Is there a way to get data and compare it from a site with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm rather new to JavaScript (but have experience) and was wondering if it's possible to get information from the content on a website (blog), such as a post title or something of that sort, save that into an array, then have the JavaScript re-analyze that site in the future, save that data into the array as well, then compare both elements in the array?

I just want to know if the concept is executable? If it won't work, why not? Data storage? Input and output restriction?

Is there another language that could do that?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Everything's possible (I mean, from your post). If you mean web scraping, probably the easiest way is Python. But really, the question is too broad and as it stands most languages can do it and there are multiple ways to do it. Just approach it step by step, problem by problem.

Comment: If you're referring to javascript running in a browser environment, you won't be able to access the website content across domain boundaries. Read on [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily in JavaScript, but you can't do it in JavaScript *in a web browser*. Instead, you can use [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) which is designed for this very kind of thing. Node.js runs JavaScript as a standalone app on a server or on your local machine, so it isn't subject to the same-domain restrictions as JavaScript in a web browser.

Of course, once you're outside the web browser, you're no longer limited to JavaScript. You can use Python or Ruby or any number of languages. But if you want to use JavaScript for this task, node.js is a fine way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes, this can be done in JavaScript.

Yes, most other programming languages can also do it.